# It's all right here

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

> What's my *actual* first name, you know, like [IRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_life#As_distinct_from_the_Internet), or [AFK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFK#Prepositional_phrase)?

All that you need to know is right here, on this page.

Of course, site administrators and the like who have access to ***this*** stuff...

[image]

...should, of course, bow out or be subject to:

- intense public scrutiny
- flogging
- being run out of town on rails
- being tarred and feathered
- down-voting

...or *worse!* Use your wicked, *wicked,* imagination!

Please remember when submitting answers which are:

1   bold
2   intrepid
3   unafraid
4   uncurbed
5   undaunted
6   ungoverned
7   brave
8   resolute
9   venturesome
10  enterprising
11  daredevilish
12  rash
13  adventurous
14  aweless
15  courageous
16  dauntless
17  fearless
18  shameless
19  smart ass
20  valiant
21  brassy
22  cheeky
23  foolhardy
24  gutty
25  nervy
26  risky

...*Chowzen* reserves the right to down-vote said answers.

So, how about it?

> Can you guess my real name?

---

---

HINT:
In response to @HollyLeaves partial answer/observation, I offer this:

> 10.5, 8.2, 6.10, 12.4, 14.3, 26.1, 23.7, 3.7, 20.6, 24.1

HINT #2:

> The **entire** body of my question *could* have been this: "What's my actual first name? All that you need to know is right here, on this page."

Comment: (PSE mods do in fact have access to something that may well be Chowzen's real name. I, at least, am therefore keeping away from this puzzle as per Chowzen's request.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan darn, I was looking forward to seeing you tarred and feathered.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan (wondering...) does that mean that you *see* it but can't answer? :)

Comment: @thecoder16 I think down-voting is the cruelest wicked punishment :p

Comment: I think a steganography tag would work here, but please remove it if you disagree.

Comment: @North Maybe this is a question for META... Does adding tags to an "enigmatic" puzzle defeat its *enigmaticness?*

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Just out of curiosity, was his name Scott?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the hint says

> The entire body of my question could have been this: "What's my actual first name? All that you need to know is right here, on this page."

I think the message is

> in the avatar. The full size avatar has no metadata nor anything in the hexdump besides random data (`LEO` and `oLAF` are interesting ones). [image]
>
> A reverse image search also gives nothing. 
>  
>  
>  However, the answer might be simpler. As R.M. states in the comments, this looks like it spells `Scott`.

Comment: Maybe the avatar is a signature, and his name is Scott? Or something like that with those letters?

Answer (score 5):

So I've noticed that

> The last letter of each word is in alphabetical order, and many end in the same letter
>  There are 26 words, corresponding to 26 letters?

I don't know if these are intentional, and even if they are I have no idea what to do with it.

Edit: So the ""Hint"" is:

> redherring
>  Found by taking the given letter of the numbered word.
>  eg: 5th letter of the 10th word in 10.5

Guess it doesn't actually mean anything, but it was the best I could come up with. xd

Comment: Within the groups your spoiler talks about, the words themselves look to be similarly ordered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about this, but since you said in the hint that

> The entire body of my question could have been this: "What's my actual first name? All that you need to know is right here, on this page."

Maybe it's

> Allrighthere

> Because that's what the title says. Literally. :)

Probably not though...

Comment: The fact that my mother is still alive and kicking (meaning I haven't killed her), suggests strongly that she didn't put "Allrighthere" on my birth certificate where it says "First Name." Fun Fact: Presently one of the top 500 most popular first names, *(name)* has been a top 500 placer since the Social Security Administration began keeping records in 1880.